# Magento CE 1.7 "updated_at" for sales_flat_order not updating with new shipping address

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping

Is a known issue? I use shipstation to manage our warehouse and it updates based on updated_at value in the database.

When a customer updates their shipping address, the updated_at date remains the same. As you can imagine, this is a big deal. So my 2nd question: is there anything else that we know about which does not update the update_at value?

Answer (score 2):

The field `updated_at` is infamous for its many problems. This was solved in the bugathon in 2013 and subsequently fixed in 1.8CE:

https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/issues/235

However, the timestamp field itself will only 'update' if MySQL receives an update statement, because that's how the schema is set - the table row itself must be updated in order for the timestamp to auto-update; child foreign keys don't manually propagate. In this case it may be beneficial for you to modify or extend Shipstation in order to update the field manually.

Comment: Thanks. One thing I need to get better at is figuring out events in Magento. How can I find the event that fires when order shipping address is changed?

Comment: Oh, I should just guess? <sales_order_address_save_after> Cool, that worked :)

Comment: Good job! Yes, that's the one. If this helped let's go ahead and accept or clarify your question so we can get a final answer. We're trying to close all open questions. Thanks!

Comment: I have the event correctly firing, but what is the best approach to take that $event data and updating the 'updated_at' value in the database? I can't even seem to get the order from "->getOrder()"